# How to generate random numbers between 2 values?

Tags: javascript, random

I'm trying to create JS script that will generate random numbers between 2 values. But it doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

```
<form id="form" action="" method="get">
From: <input type="text" name="from" id="from"><br>
To: <input type="text" name="to" id="to"><br><br>
<button onclick="random_gen()">Generate</button>
</form>

    <script>
    function random_gen() {
    var a = document.getElementById("from").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("to").value;
    var c = Math.floor((Math.random() * b) + a);
    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = c;
    return false;
    }
    </script>

<p id="final"></p>
```

PS I'm new at JS

Comment: Should be `<button type=button ...`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7NDEn/

Comment: @Pointy: why would button need a type?

Comment: @dandavis Technically, that button is submitting the form, so that could be the "problem" - the OP may see the page reload because the form is submitted (and therefore it looks like the `.innerHTML = c;` isn't happening. Then again, this may not be the problem the OP has at all

Comment: @dandavis there are three possible types, and this should make it obvious: "button", "reset", and "submit". The last one is the default.

Comment: @Pointy: the button doesn't seem to be submitting, even without the "return false": http://jsfiddle.net/7NDEn/1/ i'm just curoius if it's actually needed or just one of those things we do "just because" or for readability...

Comment: @dandavis You don't have a form in that jsFiddle...and the `return false` would need another change for it to work anyways

Comment: @Ian: that explains a lot ;) dan need more coffee... i knew it wasn't Pointy that was wrong...

Comment: @blex tnq, you helped me a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited to reflect the comment from @blex, which is correct

The correct algorithm for random is:

```
function rand(a,b){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(b-a)+a);
}
```

When retrieving the values from an input, you must do parseInt:

```
var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("from").value);
var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("to").value);
```

Of course, you should check the values to make sure they are integers before you use them.

Comment: and to add `parseInt` to _a_ and _b_, and remove the <form> tags because the form gets sent instead of just executing the code. works with negative numbers: http://jsfiddle.net/7NDEn/

Comment: You usually don't want to use `parseInt` with user input unless you want to let them put invalid characters at the end of a number. For example, `parseInt("2342asdf")` will result in `2342` (sometimes that isn't desired). I like to be explicit/strict and use `Number("2342asdf")` (or `+"2342asdf"`) which would result in `NaN` - this converts to a number, unrelated to decimal points. In addition, you normally want to include the radix as the second parameter (`10` for base 10) - `parseInt("2342asdf", 10)` - because some inputs may force the parser to use octal or hex, for example

Answer (score 0):

Your element's values will be strings. You're going to wind up with a weird number, because you're generating a random number with `Math.random() * b`, which converts `b` to a number, and then *concatenating* the string contained in `a` to it.

Lets assume the following:

```
var a = '10';
var b = '20';
```

So, `Math.random() * b` works fine. It gives you a value like `15.12345`. The problem is, you're concatenating the *string* `"10"` to the result, giving you *a string*, `15.1234510`, which is passed to `Math.floor`, and converted back to the number `15`.

You need to convert both of your inputs to numbers before passing them through your `rand` process. Use `parseInt` for this:

```
var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("from").value, 10);
var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("to").value, 10);
```

Comment: So, how should I do it?

Comment: See update. `parseInt` will turn both values into integers. If you want to use decimal values as your inputs, use `parseFloat` instead.

Comment: @meagar, the random must be multiplied by (b-a), otherwise his range is incorrect